# How can I prevent "yyyy-mm-dd" from breaking within the string

Tags: css, word-wrap

I have block of strings (below) that looks like this:

022-05-26 2022-05-25 2022-05-24 2022-05-23 2022-05-19 2022-05-18 2022-05-14 2022-05-11 2022-05-10 2022-05-09 2022-05-08 2022-05-05 2022-05-04 2022-05-03 2022-05-02 2022-05-01

But displayed in a div in a web page the words are split at the YYYY-MM-DD dashes (interpretted an hyphens) which I don't want it do:

```
022-05-26 2022-05-25 2022-05-24 2022-05-23 2022-05-19 2022-05-18 2022-05-14 2022-05-
11 2022-05-10 2022-05-09 2022-05-08 2022-05-05 2022-05-04 2022-05-03 2022-05-02 2022-05-01
```

I have tried css solutions to keep the word from breaking. overflow-wrap and word-break were not useful.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Replace ordinary hyphen with non-breaking hyphen &#8209;

Comment: Which browser do you use? Using Firefox there does not seem to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with only CSS, but you could just wrap each date in a span/div and style it with something like

```
span.date-block { 
   display: inline-block;
   whitespace: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: The text is array data used in several functions. It would be tiresome to modify the code.